# Trying to access a url using curl

Tags: php, bash, curl

I'm trying to access access a URL using Curl, inn which I would like to status of the url, whether it is redirected, not found, suceess etc...
The code I'm using is working at certain times, but not always..

```
curl -u 98ur5t9@:9@98ur5t -v --silent --request GET "http://$url/laber.txt" --include 2>&1 | grep -q "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" 2> /dev/null 
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
   echo 'url ok'
else 
   echo 'url not oke'
fi
```

Can anyone help me with how do I get the correct status and if it is 200 echo ok as output..

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -u 98ur5t9@:9@98ur5t -s -I http://www.example.org | grep  -q "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
   echo 'url ok'
else 
   echo 'url not oke'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `--head` to get only the response headers, something like:

```
response=$(curl --head -s -u 98ur5t9@:9@98ur5t GET "http://$url/laber.txt")
if [[ $response =~ 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' ]]; then
    echo 'url ok'
else
    echo 'url NOT ok'
fi
```